# Apache Spark - Delta Lake Structured Streaming: Empty Batch: 0 leads to Null pointer exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nullpointerexception, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I am trying to read an MQTT stream using Apache Spark and Apache Bahir for MQTT. I use as a sink a Delta table. However, when I start the program it always crashes giving a Null Pointer Exception. I noticed that when the program starts the first batch is empty. I am suspecting this is what causes the problem, but I can't seem to find how to solve this problem. The code I use is shown below:

```
val topic = "temp"
val brokerUrl = "tcp://localhost:1883"
val lines = spark.readStream
  .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
  .option("topic", topic).option("persistence", "memory")
  .load(brokerUrl)
  .select("payload")
  .as[Array[Byte]]
  .map(payload => new String(payload))
  .toDF("payload")

val query = lines.writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "delta/events/_checkpoints/etl-from-json")
  .start("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/admin/delta-table-localhost-02")

query.awaitTermination()
```

You can see the stack trace below:

```
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 9d4b36f4-3d16-4689-a561-f2b00c55ca7f, runId = 2d6cf038-ea50-4186-8614-c59ab943e3e5]
Current Committed Offsets: {MQTTStreamSource[brokerUrl: tcp://localhost:1883, topic: temp clientId: paho428547487727]: -1}
Current Available Offsets: {MQTTStreamSource[brokerUrl: tcp://localhost:1883, topic: temp clientId: paho428547487727]: 1}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
Project [value#14 AS payload#16]
+- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#14]
   +- MapElements BahirStructuredStreaming$$$Lambda$931/277155095@5aa41140, class [B, [StructField(value,BinaryType,true)], obj#13: java.lang.String
      +- DeserializeToObject cast(payload#2 as binary), obj#12: binary
         +- Project [payload#2]
            +- StreamingExecutionRelation MQTTStreamSource[brokerUrl: tcp://localhost:1883, topic: temp clientId: paho428547487727], [id#0, topic#1, payload#2, timestamp#3]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.LocalMessageStore.get(MessageStore.scala:119)
    at org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.LocalMessageStore.retrieve(MessageStore.scala:143)
    at org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSource.$anonfun$planInputPartitions$2(MQTTStreamSource.scala:179)
    at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse$(MapLike.scala:129)
    at scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap.getOrElse(TrieMap.scala:625)
    at org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSource.$anonfun$planInputPartitions$1(MQTTStreamSource.scala:179)
    at org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSource.$anonfun$planInputPartitions$1$adapted(MQTTStreamSource.scala:178)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:285)
    at scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.foreach(NumericRange.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:285)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:278)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSource.planInputPartitions(MQTTStreamSource.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.partitions$lzycompute(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.partitions(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.outputPartitioning(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.$anonfun$ensureDistributionAndOrdering$1(EnsureRequirements.scala:150)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$exchange$EnsureRequirements$$ensureDistributionAndOrdering(EnsureRequirements.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(EnsureRequirements.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(EnsureRequirements.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$2(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.apply(EnsureRequirements.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.apply(EnsureRequirements.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$prepareForExecution$1(QueryExecution.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.prepareForExecution(QueryExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$13(MicroBatchExecution.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:198)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this `NullPointerException` using the exact same code with delta-lake version 0.6.1, spark version 2.4.0, bahir 2.4.0 compiled with scala 2.12. What version of delta-lake do you use ? What exact version of spark do you use ?

Comment: Can you also add the complete stack trace to your question ?

Comment: @VincentDoba The exact same versions you mentioned.

Comment: I realized that if I delete the folder delta (the one containing the checkpoint of the stream) in my project, the folder then is created again and the program works fine. I'll search more for it to come to a more clear answer, or if you have any idea you can post the answer, too!